# Stop Python smtpd DebuggingServer

Tags: python, smtplib

I started a local server in Terminal using:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

How do I stop or undo this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `ctrl+d` from terminal.

Comment: After entering `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025` nothing happens actually. Does this mean that local server didn't start?

I had to press ctrl+c twice to terminate; will that work?

Comment: No. If you don't have error thrown, it should be good. To confirm you can try to send an e-mail through your server